# Using the bash eval builtin to allow ini files to have command strings in them

Tags: bash, shell, variables, eval

I've been putting together a bash script that takes an ini file (with a format that I've been developing alongside the script) and reads through the file, performing the actions specified.

One of the functions in the ini format allows for a shell command to be passed in and run using `eval`. I'm running into a problem when the commands contain a variable name.

`eval` (or the shell in general) doesn't seem to be substituting the values correctly and most of the time it seems to replace all the variable names with blanks, breaking the command. Subshells to create a string output seem to have the same problem.

The strange part is that this worked on my development machine (Running linux mint 13), but when I moved the script to the target machine running CentOS 5.8, these issues showed up.

Some examples of code I read in from the ini file:

```
shellcmd $toolspath/program > /path/file

shellcmd parsedata=$( cat /path/file )
```

These go through a script function that strips off the leading `shellcmd` and then evals the string using

```
eval ${scmd}
```

Any ideas on what might be causing the weird behavior and anything I can try to resolve the problem? My ultimate goal here is to have the ability to read in a line from a file and have my script execute it and be able to correctly handle script variables from the read in command.

Comment: It would be a good idea to create a minimal example with a hardcoded command where `eval` doesn't behave the way you want. For example: `a=1; cmd='echo $a > foo'; eval $cmd`

Comment: Since you stated that it works on Linux Mint 13 but not CentOS 5.8, maybe this comes from different bash version or shell? (For example, /bin/sh is default to dash on debian and Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

Using Bash 3.2.25 (CentOS 5) I tried this, and it works fine:

```
toolspath='/bin'
while read prefix scmd
do
    if [[ $prefix == 'shellcmd' ]]
    then
        echo "Evaluating: <$scmd>"
        eval ${scmd}
    else
        echo "$prefix ignored"
    fi
done < ini
```

with:

```
shellcmd $toolspath/ls > /home/user1/file     
shellcmd parsedata=$( cat /home/user1/file )
shellcmd echo $parsedata
```

I obviously had to set paths.  Most likely you had to change the paths when you switched machines.  Do your paths have embedded spaces?

How did you transfer the files?  Did you perchance go via Windows?  On a whim I did a `unix2dos` on the `ini` file and I got similar symptoms to that you describe.  That's my best guess.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Your code seems to work fine, but I still don't see why my code isn't working (even though your code is pretty much identical).

The paths do not have spaces, but they do have a dot (.) in front of some of the directories. The paths are quoted when the variables are set.

These files were developed completely on linux machines and transferred directly using thumb drives (windows hasn't touched the files). I ran the files through dos2unix anyways just to make sure and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Can I suggest that you try with just a single statement that fails, and run it through using `bash -x script-name` to get a trace.  If I hear you right, my code works and yours fails?  Maybe if you posted all your code we might have a better idea.

Comment: I think I may have traced it to the specific command I'm trying to run an eval on. The tool I'm trying to call is a monitoring tool that constantly updates the screen, but has an option to only show one output tick instead of a constant update. When I cat the file manually it clears the screen and shows only the contents of the file, and when I open it in gedit I see some nonprinting characters at the top. Maybe there's something different when running in script mode versus interactively that causes the script to behave differently when it sees the nonprinting character.

Comment: With some further investigation it looks like this issue is related to a specific tool that I need to call with the script. It puts in a terminal code ^[H^[J at the beginning of it's output (with the ^[ being the escape character) and that seems to cause problems with the shell for some reason. I tried piping the output through sed to remove the character, but it seems to be causing problems as soon as it's read before any contingency code can be run to address the issue. Any suggestions on how to get bash to temporarily ignore terminal codes?

Comment: The obvious answer is to change the tool that is generating these characters.  Why is it generating them?

Comment: How did you try to get rid of them using `sed`?  To remove the first two chars its just `'s/^..//'` (don't strictly need the ^ but its easier to read).  Did you try to sanitize the file before you call `read`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a suitable alternative for the one command that what causing this issue so I'll mark this question as solved.

From all my investigation it appears that I've discovered an obscure bug in the bash shell. The particular command I was trying to eval returned a terminal code in it's output, and because the shell was in a read loop with input redirected from a file it resulted in some strange behavior. My solution was to move the call to this particular command outside of the read loop. It still doesn't solve the root problem, which I believe to be a bug in the bash shell. Hope this will help someone else who has run into this same (obscure) issue.

Comment: I would say its a bug in the code generating those characters, not Bash.